# Doubt in computing $g^\frac{1}{\delta+x}$ where $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elliptic-curves, zero-knowledge-proofs, group-theory

I was going through [Zero Knowledge Set Membership](https://www.ingwb.com/media/2667856/zero-knowledge-set-membership.pdf) and came across the following:

Given $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $g$ is the generator of a multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}$ how do we compute $g^\frac{1}{\delta+x}$.

My doubt is, since $\mathbb{G}$ is a multiplicative group, doesn't that require $\frac{1}{\delta + x} \in \mathbb{Z}$. But since $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is that possible?

Please help me understand this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $g^\frac{1}{\delta+x} = g^{{(\delta+x)}^{-1}}$.

Comment: The division is modulo the order of the group (which is hopefully prime).

Comment: To be more explicit, in this context $\frac{1}{\delta+x}$ stands for that number $y$ such that $y \times (\delta + x) = 1$ modulo the order of $g$